# PVE Connect to Wi-Fi from CLI

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, wifi, ntfs, proxmox

I need to format a partition as read-write ntfs, but right now it can only do it as read-only. In order to accomplish my needs I need to apt-get ntfs-3g, but in order to do that I need the machine to connect via. Wi-Fi to my hotspot. It is currently not possible to connect it via ethernet.

The machine is an HP Elitebook 840 running Proxmox 6.01, with a wireless interface: wlo1
The proxmox system does not have the following network-related commands/utilities:
- scan
- ifconfig
- iwconfig
- wpa_supplicant
- wpa_cli
- nmcli
- iwctl
- iwlist

So just about every guide I've found online isn't valid for me.

I do have access to a Windows computer with an internet connection, can I maybe download the ntfs-3g package from that and transfer to the Proxmox machine by USB?

I appreciate all the help I can get on this as I am absolutely lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB disk you could use [Gparted](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php).  Boot from the USB drive format your disk and reboot back into your original system.
The link above gives download and installation instructions which you could use from your internet connected Windows  computer.